# custom auth of two different users using two tables. i don't want to use make:auth

Tags: laravel

The first auth system works very fine its code is below and needed to have to different users using two different tables am using laravel 5.5

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class StudentController extends Controller
{   


    public function Register(Request $request)
    {

        $firstname = $request['firstname'];
        $othername = $request['othername'];
        $email = $request['email'];
        $password = $request['password'];

        $user = new User();
        $user->firstname = $firstname;
        $user->othername = $othername;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()->route('studentDashboard');

    }


    public function Login(Request $request)
    {

      if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request['email'], 'password'=> 
$request['password']]))
      {
       return redirect()->route('studentDashboard');
      }
      return redirect()->back();

    }

}
```

i duplicated the above to create auth for a different user.The registration works but the login does not work even if the login data is right it returns the redirect back after the if statement

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Employer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class EmployerController extends Controller
{

  public function createEmployerAccount(Request $request)
  {
      $companyName = $request['companyname'];
      $companyEmail = $request['email'];
      $companyPasword = $request['password'];

      $Employer = new Employer();

      $Employer->companyname = $companyName;
      $Employer->email = $companyEmail;
      $Employer->password = $companyPasword;

      $Employer->save();

      Auth::login($Employer);

      return redirect()->route('employersDashboard');

  }

  public function signInEmployer(Request $request)
  {    

       if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'], 
'password'=>$request['password']]))
        {

        return redirect()->route('employersDashboard');
      }
       return redirect()->back();
}

}
```

when i try to change the 'email' to 'emails' an error is shown->the select query is from the users table not employers table that i need to get data from and also when i change 'password' to 'passwords' an error "undefined index password" is shown

this is the route file content

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    return view('pages.index');
})->name('home');

Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses'=>'StudentController@Register',
    'as'=> 'signup'
]);

Route::post('/signin',[
    'uses'=>'StudentController@Login',
    'as'=>'signin'
]);

Route::get('/employers',[
    'uses'=>'PageController@employersPage',
    'as'=>'employers'
]);

Route::get('/studentDashboard',[
    'uses'=>'PageController@getStudentDashboard',
    'as'=> 'studentDashboard'
]);




Route::post('/createcompany',[
    'uses'=>'EmployerController@createEmployerAccount',
    'as'=>'createcompany'
]);

Route::post('/signInEmployer',[
    'uses'=>'EmployerController@signInEmployer',
    'as'=>'signInEmployer'
]);

Route::get('/employersDashboard',[
    'uses'=>'PageController@getEmployersDashboard',
    'as'=> 'employersDashboard',
    'middleware'=>'auth:employer'
]);

Route::post('/createPost',[
    'uses'=>'PostController@postCreatePost',
    'as'=> 'createPost'
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `Auth` to use different `Guard` for authentication at time of `Employer` login. To define guards for `Employer` change like this in your `config/auth.php`.

Look for `guards` section in `auth.php` and add your new guard

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'employer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'employers',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Now in the same file there is a `providers` section. You need to add `employers` provider

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        //Employer provider
        'employers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent', 
            'model' => App\Employer::class,
        ],
    ],
```

**Create a custom Auth middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class AuthenticateEmployer
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //If request does not comes from logged in employer
        //then he shall be redirected to employer Login page
        if (!Auth::guard('employer')->check()) {
            return redirect('/signInEmployer');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register custom auth middleware in Kernal.php in `routeMiddleware`

```
'employerAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateEmployer::class,
```

Now we have setup our custom `guard` and custom middleware `employerAuth`

**EmployerController**

```
class EmployerController extends Controller
{

    //either you have to define this or you can use `Auth::guard('employer')->attempt($credentials)` in login 

    protected function guard() 
    {
       return Auth::guard('employer');
    }

    public function signInEmployer(Request $request)
    {    
        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'], 
    'password'=>$request['password']]))
        {
            return redirect()->route('employersDashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

For all the routes protected by `Employer` auth, you either need to add middleware `employerAuth` in routes or add `employerAuth` in each controller `construct` like this

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('employerAuth');
}
```

Hope it may help you. For details you can check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users

Check this nice sample app for multi auth application https://github.com/yskoverride/Various2.0/tree/master/app

Comment: what route you have used ? can you add your route file content ?

Comment: why have you added middleware in `/signInEmployer` route. this middleware is added in routes that has to access after authenticated, remove middleware from this route

Comment: i've added it above do you think i need a custom middleware? and how do i go abotu it?

Comment: if you want then you can add, separate middleware but you can use the `auth` middleware with `employer` guard. Only the difference is that you always provide the guard name in auth when you have to authenticate employer

Comment: using the auth middleware ive made the changes but this time the redirect back runs.when i replace the redirect back with redirect->route('dashboard') it returns the same error

Comment: yes, you can use the `auth:employer` middleware for protect your employer routes. but don't add it in login or signup route or any controller that has login and signup action

Comment: i've made the changes but it returns the redirect back even if the credentials are right then i tried to /employersdashboard in the browser and it returns the same message "login not defined"

Comment: ive replaced the redirect->back with redirect-route('employerdashboard') and still says login not defined

Comment: i have updated answer with adding custom `auth` middleware. implement it like this

Comment: @K.Nehe i have added a sample link for Multi auth implementation. check that

Comment: can i edit the post so that you see the bug  i've followed all steps but still having that login not defined error

Comment: i have added a link at last of my answer you can follow it.

Comment: same problem the if statement in the sign in function returns false

Comment: did you follow the link that i have added at bottom ?

Comment: i've followed it. i think the problem is the model because even when right info is provided login doesnt work and now the dashboard guards aint working

Comment: check all folders in that app and implement it step by step