# 2 User Models with different Authentication Process in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm working with an app that has an Backend API for mobile and Web Login for Administrators. The authentication of Backend API was `jwt-auth 0.5.*` and for my Administrators I used the session driver.

This is the default of auth:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'web' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'users',
],

 'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'admins',
],
```

The Backend API Authentication works but the Web Admin Authentication doesn't save the session of the logged in administrator. By the way I created a guard for administrators.

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: How are attempting login? Is it like: `Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']])`

Comment: yes, i tried that and it works but if i return the authenticated user, tit will return null in the process

Comment: It should work as I've the same situation & working.

Comment: but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: you can get idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149711/custom-auth-of-two-different-users-using-two-tables-i-dont-want-to-use-makeau

Comment: maybe there's something wrong with your provider?